# Create SVG object from string

Tags: javascript, xml, svg

How can I create new SVG object from a string in JavaScript?

Object to string

```
var str = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(SvgDoc.getElementById(nameID));
```

String to object

```
var oParser = new DOMParser();
var oDOM = oParser.parseFromString(str, "image/svg+xml");
```

But oDOM isn't an SVGGElement object.

Comment: I want to create SVG object from XML string. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes it's work Thanks).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var oParser = new DOMParser();
var oDOM = oParser.parseFromString(str, "image/svg+xml");
```

will give you a Document object. You can get the root element of a document via

```
var root = oDOM.documentElement;
```